# How to Hide Or Remove URL Rewrite Management in Sub Menu in Magento

Tags: menu, magento-1.9

Can anyone help me on how to remove or rather hide a sub menu in any of the menus in magento.

The image below may describe what I need in a clearer manner.

I want to, let's say hide the URL Rewrite Management.

How will I do it.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

//Working example code for remove catalog->url rewrite management sub menu.(As per below screenshot)

//Create a file called adminhtml.xml under /etc folder of your module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog>        
          <children>
            <urlrewrite> <!-- Same as <convert> -->
                <depends>
                    <module>HideMe</module> <!-- Fake dependance to hide menu item -->
                </depends>
            </urlrewrite>
          </children>          
         </catalog>   
    </menu>
</config>
```

[More details](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/21/magento-how-to-hide-menu-items-of-admin-panel/&grqid=-5JQukNS&hl=en-IN)

[image]

Comment: It's not a detailed answer in that link. HOw do I do it?

Comment: Can I ask for Folder Path wherein I will create adminhtml.xml. Please Advice.

Comment: Create file in your any of the custom module or create separate module for this.